# Angular Controller Logic vs Vanilla JS logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Hey I'm trying to feed a database of "players" from my node backend to an angular front end and then construct rosters out of these players in my controller on the frontend.

Basically, I'm trying to do in my angular controller what this javascript I posted below does...except with my mean app all the players are contained within one object and first need to be separated by position. Then a lineup can be created.

I've been hacking away in my controller for a few days trying to get it work, but can't figure it out how I...

- can save all the players to a variable
- then, seperate them out by position
- then, select players at random
  — then, once a lineup is created — check it for duplicates and that it makes it below the salary cap

Here's my controller first, so far I can save the list of players to $scope, but then can't figure out how to go further...the javascript example is below it...

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name clientApp.controller:PlayersCtrl
 * @description
 * # PlayersCtrl
 * Controller of the clientApp
 */
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('PlayersCtrl', function ($scope, Player, $q) {

    console.log(Player);
    $scope.players = Player.getList().$object;
    console.log($scope.players);


});

— End of Controller, vanilla JS below...
```

```js
var SalaryCap = 60000;

var Roster = [];

var QBs = {
  DrewBrees : 8000,
  MattRyan : 7000,
  MatthewStafford : 6000,
  TomBrady : 10000,
  JayCutler : 6500,
  AaronRodgers : 9000,
  PhillipRivers : 8500,
  TeddyBridgewater : 6000

};

var RBs = {
  AdrianPeterson : 9000,
  ToddGurley : 9500,
  DevontaFreeman : 8500,
  FrankGore : 7000,
  MattForte : 7500,
  ArianFoster : 8000
};

var WRs ={
  DeAndreHopkins : 8900,
  OdellBeckhamJr : 8800,
  AntonioBrown : 8700,
  AJGreen : 8300,
  DezBryant : 8100,
  JulianEdelman : 8000,
  CalvinJohnson : 8000,
  DemaryiusThomas : 7900,
  EmmanuelSanders : 7800,
  RandallCobb : 7700,
  MikeEvans : 7700,
  // AlshonJeffery : 7600,
  // AllenRobinson : 7500,
  // LarryFitzgerald : 7400,
  // AllenHurns : 7300,
  // BrandinCooks : 7200,
  // AmariCooper : 7100,
  // JarvisLandry : 7000,
  // StefonDiggs : 6600,
  // JordanMatthews : 6600,
  // MartavisBryant : 6500,
  // JeremyMaclin: 6500,
  // WillieSnead : 6500,
  // PierreGarcon : 6400
};

var TEs = {
  RobGronkowski : 8000,
  GregOlsen : 6300,
  TylerEifert : 6200,
  GaryBarnidge : 6100,
  JimmyGraham : 6000,
  DelanieWalker : 5900,
  JordanReed : 5800,
  TravisKelce : 5800,
  JasonWitten : 5600,
  BenjaminWatson : 5500,
  RichardRodgers : 5400
};

var Ks = {
  StephenGostkowski : 5100,
  CalebSturgis : 5000,
  StevenHauschka : 5000,
  MasonCrosby : 5000,
  BlairWalsh : 4900,
  JustinTucker : 4900,
  BrandonMcManus : 4800,
  JoshBrown : 4800,
  ConnorBarth : 4800,
  KaiForath : 4700,
  ChandlerCantanzaro : 4700
};

var DEFs = {
  StLouisRams : 5400,
  DenverBroncos : 5200,
  CincinattiBengals : 5000,
  SeattleSeahawks : 4900,
  NewEnglandPatriots : 4900,
  GreenBayPackers : 4900,
  ArizonaCardinals : 4700,
  CarolinaPanthers : 4700,
  PhiladelphiaEagles : 4700,
  PittsburghSteelers : 4600,
  DallasCowboys : 4600,
  MinnesotaVikings : 4500,
  NewYorkGiants : 4500,
  MiamiDolphins : 4500,
  BaltimoreRavens : 4400
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // QUARTERBACK
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
function randomQuarterback(QBs) {

  var QB = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(QBs);
  // console.log(arrayOfAllKeys);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    QB.push(objKey, QBs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(QB);
  }
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // RB1
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
function randomRunningbackOne(RBs) {

  RB1 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(RBs);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    RB1.push(objKey, RBs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(RB1);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // RB2
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function randomRunningbackTwo(RBs) {

  RB2 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(RBs);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    RB2.push(objKey, RBs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(RB2);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // WR1
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function randomWideoutOne(WRs) {

  WR1 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(WRs);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    WR1.push(objKey, WRs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(WR1);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // WR2
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function randomWideoutTwo(WRs) {

  WR2 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(WRs);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    WR2.push(objKey, WRs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(WR2);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // WR3
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function randomWideoutThree(WRs) {

  WR3 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(WRs);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    WR3.push(objKey, WRs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(WR3);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // TE1
//////////////////////////////////////////////////


function randomTEone(TEs) {

  TE1 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(TEs);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    TE1.push(objKey, TEs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(TE1);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // K
//////////////////////////////////////////////////


function randomKicker(Ks) {

  K1 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(Ks);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    K1.push(objKey, Ks[objKey]);
    Roster.push(K1);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // DEF
//////////////////////////////////////////////////


function randomDEF(DEFs) {

  DEF1 = [];

  var arrayOfAllKeys = Object.keys(DEFs);
  // console.log(arrayOfAllKeys);

  for(var i=0; i<1; i++){

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfAllKeys.length);

    var objKey = arrayOfAllKeys[rnd];

    DEF1.push(objKey, DEFs[objKey]);
    Roster.push(DEF1);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Roster Compiler
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function rosterConstruction() {
  randomQuarterback(QBs);
  randomRunningbackOne(RBs);
  randomRunningbackTwo(RBs);
  randomWideoutOne(WRs);
  randomWideoutTwo(WRs);
  randomWideoutThree(WRs);
  randomTEone(TEs);
  randomKicker(Ks);
  randomDEF(DEFs);
}
rosterConstruction();
console.log(Roster);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Duplicates Filer
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function eliminateDuplicates(roster) {

  var i;
  len=roster.length;
  console.log(len);
  var filteredRoster = [];
  obj={};

  for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
    obj[roster[i]]=0;
  }
  for (i in obj) {
    filteredRoster.push(i);
  }
  return filteredRoster;
};

var rosterWithoutDuplicates = eliminateDuplicates(Roster);
console.log(rosterWithoutDuplicates);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Salary Cap Check
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function salaryCheck(roster) {
  var i = 0;
  var checker = [];
  for(i; i < roster.length; i++) {
    checker.push(roster[i][1]);
  }
  var sum = checker.reduce(add, 0);

  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
    // console.log(checker);
  }
  return sum;
};

var totalSalary = salaryCheck(rosterWithoutDuplicates);
console.log(totalSalary);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Final Compiler
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function doubleCheck() {
  while(rosterWithoutDuplicates.length < 9 && totalSalary >= SalaryCap) {
    Roster = [];
    console.log(Roster);
    rosterConstruction();
    console.log(Roster);
    eliminateDuplicates();
    console.log(rosterWithoutDuplicates)
    salaryCheck();
    console.log(totalSalary);
    ;
    }
};
doubleCheck();
console.log(rosterWithoutDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to put your 'vanilla js' in a service and then include that service in your controller.

```
.factory('playersSrvc', function () {
  return {
    data: {
      // static data related with your domain
    },
    helpers: {
      // functions so logic that manipulates data etc.
    }
  }
}

.controller('playersCtrl', function ($scope, playersSrvc, $q) {
  $scope.data = playersSrvc.data;
  $scope.helpers = playersSrvc.helpers;

  console.log($scope.data.SalaryCap)  

});
```

Also by looking at your code

1/ angular.module('clientApp') is missing second argument (array) that refers to list on modules that clientApp module depends (pass empty [] if none).

2/ Controller name has to have first character lowercase.

Comment: alrighty, so @ChrisHermut the "data" in my service would be the list of all players from my DB, and then the "helpers" would hold all the vanilla JS that I use to make the roster from the players?

and from there I can just feed the end result into the controller?

Comment: Yes and by assigning values to $scope properties you can reference them in your view ex. <h1>{{title}}</h1> which in your controller would be $scope.title and changes to $scope.title will be reflected in your view.